# Would you help me with adverbs, such as also?

Tags: adverbs, adverb-placement

> Not only did he give everyone gifts but he invited them to a party **also**.
>
> Not only did he give everyone gifts but he invited them to a party **as well/too**.

Which one is more common? or which one is accurate or correct?

Comment: As a *non*-native, I think the first one is less common and *probably* non-standard. However, if you move *also* to the position after *he*, though, you get a typical and usual pattern 'Not only do X ... but X also ...'

Answer (score 4):

I am a native speaker, and the first sentence is not standard. It should be

> Not only did he give everyone gifts, but he **also** invited them to a party.

The second sentence is OK as is with "as well", but requires a comma before "too". It is also acceptable to put a comma before "as well", if you want.

One more thing: if you find it unusual or unexpected that he should invite people to a party, you might say

> Not only did he give everyone gifts, but he **even** invited them to a party.

The "not only" ... "but" ... "even" pattern is pretty common when someone does more than you would normally expect.